# Web API Edmx and Connection String in not cloned

Tags: entity-framework, tfs, ado.net, webapi, edmx

I have a Web API project in TFS it contains all files including `edmx` files and
`connection string` in `webConfig`

When I cloned the project all files are exist in my local machine except the `edmx` files and `connection string`.

Why those files are not coming? I tried to get the latest again and they're still not cloned.

Shall I add the Data(ADO.net) manually? is it correct way to do it? and why it's not getting cloned?

Comment: Hi @rav, how are things going? Have you checked with the suggestions in my answer? In addition, please also make sure that the branch you check out to local is same with the remote branch where the edmx files and connection string are in.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the following things:

1. How did you clone the repository? Using VS, or git clone command, or other methods? Please try different methods to see if the problem still occurs.
2. Check whether the **`.edmx`** file was added into the **`.gitignore`** (if any). If yes, remove it from the **`.gitignore`**.
3. Whether the ADO.NET Entity Data Model project was created by you? If it was created by other people, you need to confirm if the creator has set blocking other user to check out the specific files.